# broadcastlistener can`t get intent from listview adapter in fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, fragment

I have an fragments that is set in tab structure

one of those fragments, I have a vertical listview

Also in each vertical listview items, I have a horizontal listviews.

The problem is.. when I declared an intent broadcaster in horizontal adapter

and also declared broadcastlistener in main fragment but listener seems isn't listening the intent

plz help me... I'm korean student..

here is my code briefly

[In Horizontial Adapter]

```
...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View retval = convertView;

    if(convertView==null)       // initialize
    {
        retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.part_item, null);

        TextView tv_workout = (TextView)retval.findViewById(R.id.txt_work);
        ImageView iv_workout = (ImageView)retval.findViewById(R.id.pic_work);

        tv_workout.setText(getItem(rowpos).get(position).getPartname());
        iv_workout.setImageResource(getItem(rowpos).get(position).getImagesrc());

        iv_workout.setTag(position);
        iv_workout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if((int)v.getTag() == getCount()-1)
                {   
                    PartContent temp_part = new PartContent("part", R.drawable.plus);
                    PartContent temp_base_part = new PartContent("workout", R.drawable.dumb);


                    totallist.get(rowpos).set(getCount()-1, temp_base_part);
                    totallist.get(rowpos).add(temp_part);

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(getContext(), FragRoutine.class);
                    intent.putExtra("row", rowpos);
                    intent.putExtra("col", (int) v.getTag());
                    getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);


                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "one more hour!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getView((int)v.getTag(), (View)v.getParent(), (ViewGroup)v.getParent().getParent());

                    //FragRoutine fr = new FragRoutine();
                    //fr.TotalList.get(rowpos).set(getCount() - 1, temp_base_part);
                    //fr.TotalList.get(rowpos).add(temp_part);

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    else 
    {
        TextView tv_workout = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_work);
        ImageView iv_workout = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic_work);

        tv_workout.setText(getItem(rowpos).get(position).getPartname());
        iv_workout.setImageResource(getItem(rowpos).get(position).getImagesrc());

        iv_workout.setTag(position);
        iv_workout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if((int)v.getTag() == getCount() - 1)
                {   
                    PartContent temp_part = new PartContent("part", R.drawable.plus);
                    PartContent temp_base_part = new PartContent("part", R.drawable.dumb);

                    totallist.get(rowpos).set(getCount()-1, temp_base_part);
                    totallist.get(rowpos).add(temp_part);

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    //intent.setClass(getContext(), FragRoutine.class);
                    intent.putExtra("row", rowpos);
                    intent.putExtra("col", (int) v.getTag());
                    getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);


                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "last clicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getView((int)v.getTag(), (View)v.getParent(), (ViewGroup)v.getParent().getParent());

                    //FragRoutine fr = new FragRoutine();
                    //fr.TotalList.get(rowpos).set(getCount() - 1, temp_base_part);
                    //fr.TotalList.get(rowpos).add(temp_part);

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    return retval;
}
```

[broadcastlistener]

```
...


public class FragRoutine extends Fragment
{
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.schedule_routine, container,false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();        
        initializeViewObject();
    }

    private void initializeViewObject(){

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "listen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String msg_me = intent.getStringExtra("row");
            }

        };

        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You've registered your `BroadcastReceiver` with an empty `IntentFilter`. It doesn't know what to listen for, so it never gets called.

You created your broadcast `Intent` like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //intent.setClass(getContext(), FragRoutine.class);
    intent.putExtra("row", rowpos);
    intent.putExtra("col", (int) v.getTag());
    getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This `Intent` also has no ACTION, no COMPONENT and no DATA. When you broadcast this `Intent`, Android has no idea what to do with it.

Try adding a unique ACTION to both the `Intent` and the `IntentFilter. Something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("my.special.broadcast.action");
    //intent.setClass(getContext(), FragRoutine.class);
    intent.putExtra("row", rowpos);
    intent.putExtra("col", (int) v.getTag());
    getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now register your listener to listen for this `Intent` ACTION:

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter =
            new IntentFilter("my.special.broadcast.action");
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
       ...
    };
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works very well!! May be I should study about intent more.  I tried many ways but nothing worked..  :(